# WebGrid Not displaying the data

Tags: c#, asp.net, webgrid

I am working on WebGrid in  asp.net mvc3(c#).
I have done all the coding perfectly but I don't know why WebGrid is not rendering on the page.
I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have debug the code and data is there in

```
var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, defaultSort: "CRM_ID");%>
```

But, It is not displaying.

Here is my ASPX Page code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<CRMEvent.Models.CRM.DatabaseEntities.CRM_Dashboard_Requests>>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Dashboard
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2>Dashboard</h2>
    <%    
        var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, defaultSort: "CRM_ID");%>
<div id="grid">

    <%
        grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
          grid.Column(columnName: "CRM_ID",header: "CRM ID", canSort: true),
         grid.Column(columnName: "MDLNO", header: "MDLNO", canSort: true),
         grid.Column(columnName: "EMP_Name", header: "Employee", canSort: true),
         grid.Column(columnName: "SERVICE_TYPE", header: "Service Type", canSort: true),
         grid.Column(columnName: "Requested_Amount", header: "Requested Amount", canSort: true),
         grid.Column(columnName: "Created_Date", header: "Date", canSort: true)
         ));
   %>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Did you see any errors in the code ? If so please let us know

Comment: @Karthik. No error just syntax mistake. Btw It is solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this. `<%=`

```
<%= grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
          grid.Column(columnName: "CRM_ID",header: "CRM ID", canSort: true),
         grid.Column(columnName: "MDLNO", header: "MDLNO", canSort: true),
         grid.Column(columnName: "EMP_Name", header: "Employee", canSort: true),
         grid.Column(columnName: "SERVICE_TYPE", header: "Service Type", canSort: true),
         grid.Column(columnName: "Requested_Amount", header: "Requested Amount", canSort: true),
         grid.Column(columnName: "Created_Date", header: "Date", canSort: true)
         )); %>
```

or even `<%: %>` this syntax for html Encoding.